# Proper syntax for bash script line

Tags: bash

Writing a script to retrieve various environment parameters back from a list of servers. My script returns no value when ran but the same command returns the desired value outside of a script.

I have tried using a couple of variations to retrieve the same data. One of the commands fails because of restrictions placed on the accounts I have access to. The second command works but only if executed in an elevated mode.

This fails with access denied (pwdx is restricted)

```sh
dzdo pgrep -f /some/path | xargs pwdx
```

This works outside of a script but returns no value within a script

```sh
dzdo /bin/readlink -e /proc/"$(pgrep -f /some/path)"/cwd
```

When using "bash -x" to execute my scriipt, I see the "readlink" code is blank.

Ideally, I would like to return the PID and path of the process running as the "pgrep" command does. I can work with the path alone as returned by the "readlink" version returns. The end goal is to gather the information from several servers for audit purposes. (version, etc.)

Am I using the wrong syntax for the "readlink" command? I'm fairly new to coding bash scripts so I appreciate any guidance to help understand when to to what if I'm using a command in a script vs command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `pwdx` is the restricted program, you need to run that with `dzdo`, not `pgrep`.

```
pgrep -f /some/path | dzdo xargs pwdx
```

Comment: Well, that may be a facepalm moment. Thank you, that is something I had not tried. Can you enlighten me as to why "dzdo /bin/readlink -e /proc/"$(pgrep -f /some/path)"/cwd" returns nothing for "$(pgrep -f /some/path)"?

Comment: I'm not sure, I can't think of a reason why `pgrep` would work differently in the command substitution.